# How node.js get the Linux release version?

Tags: node.js, linux

How can I get linux release version? For example, when my code run on a CentOS linux, i could get 'CentOS', if Ubuntu get 'Ubuntu'. I have seen the os module node it self, but can not find any api of this.

Comment: so os.release(); //'10.8.0' this didn't worked for you.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that nothing in the OS module exists to identify the linux distribution. You can get it this way:

```
exec('cat /etc/*release | grep -E ^NAME', function(error, stdout, stderr) {
    //stdout contains NAME="CentOS Linux", NAME=Fedora depending, ...
    //parse the string to get what you want
});
```

Source: http://www.novell.com/coolsolutions/feature/11251.html